# Using Java OutputStream

Tags: java, file-io, outputstream

I need to print a representation of an ArrayList of strings to the given output stream (out):

```
public void outputBag(OutputStream out)
        throws IOException
{


}
```

I'd usually do this in the main function by using writer and be done with it. But I have to use the above method this time. Thing is, I have no idea how OutputStream is supposed to work, I spent a couple of hours reading javadocs and watching videos but to no avail.

Can you guys show me an example of how I'd do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java's streams, readers, and writers are modular and designed to work together. Usually you wrap bare `OutputStream`s in something with a richer interface, like a `PrintStream`, to make it easier to use. So, for example:

```
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(out);
ps.print("The array list has this many elements: ");
ps.println(theArrayList.size());
ps.println(theArrayList.toString());
ps.flush();
```

I don't know what your "string representation of an ArrayList" should be, so I just made something up; you may want to do something different, but it would be similar in spirit.